# Smartphone ribbon connector identification

Tags: pcb, connector

I need to replace this 78-pins connector on a smartphone PCB (Galaxy A40) but I can't find its name (dimensions in cm):
[image]

Here is the ribbon cable:
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Shopping questions are forbidden, so you should probably concentrate on what it is rather than where it's sold. You should also read the site tour and guidelines on component identification questions.  In particular for connectors you need dimensions and pin/contact pitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those kind of connectors for smartphones are designed and manufactured by:

JST, Molex, TE, Amphenol, JAE

My guess is that the pitch is 0.3 mm or 0.4 mm.

Go to digikey.com and search by:

microminiature board to board connectors

or

fine pitch board to board connectors